# Cover page Visualstudio solution

Tags: visual-studio

I want to know if there is a way to add a cover page to a Visual Studio solution. Is there any extension which allows me to add for example a HTML file, which gets displayed in VS every time I open the solution. I am working with VS versions 2013 and 2015.

Thank you for your help.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code as a [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) C# extension to open a startup.html file from the solution directory on opening a solution:

```
public class E : VisualCommanderExt.IExtension
{
    public void SetSite(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE_, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
    {
        DTE = DTE_;
        events = DTE.Events;
        solutionEvents = events.SolutionEvents;
        solutionEvents.Opened += OnSolutionOpened;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        solutionEvents.Opened -= OnSolutionOpened;
    }

    private void OnSolutionOpened()
    {
        try
        {
            string startupFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(DTE.Solution.FullName), "startup.html");
            DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile(startupFile);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE;
    private EnvDTE.Events events;
    private EnvDTE.SolutionEvents solutionEvents;
}
```

Comment: Wow this is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much